# Selecting 50 million SQL Server records in one go versus batches to analyze text field

Tags: c#-4.0, sql-server-2012

All data I need in a TEXT field, from which multiple pairs need to be extracted using IndexOf, Substring. Is SqlDataReader with large CommandTimeout the best option to do that in one go?

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
command.CommandTimeout = 1000;
```

Below standard query which returns 50 million records

```
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connStr))
            {

                string query = "SELECT  text_data,pk from table1 with (nolock) " + 
                               " where applicationCode = 'XYZ' and direction = 'ABC' " ;
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
                command.CommandTimeout = 1800;
                connection.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
               {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        string text_data = reader.GetString(0);
                        // string processing
```

Instead it may be run many times by restricting where clause

```
+ " and  transmitDate between '20150101' and '20150102'";
```

get results

```
   + " and  transmitDate between '20150102' and '20150103'";
```

get results
...

Initially I had a problem with "one go" approach.The number of read records was outputted to console window ( 100 increments -  totCount % 100 == 0  ) and it was stuck after reading let's say 15000 records, which triggered this question. It doesn't seem to be the case anymore after outputting for each record plus before/after getting text, though, I guess,something just changed at server side.

```
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Before getting text " );
                string text_data = reader.GetString(0);
                Console.WriteLine("After getting text ");
                Console.WriteLine("Read " + totCount++);
```

Is anything wrong generally speaking with the query which returns millions of records ( impact on other users ) and runs for hours ? Should we always try to avoid that and use multiple queries instead where it is possible.

Comment: This is very vague: "All data I need in a TEXT field, from which multiple pairs need to be extracted using IndexOf, Substring." That's really not enough information about what you're trying to achieve. Can you not perform the matching in the database?

Comment: It seems that you need somethig like Full Text Search.

Comment: @Jon I need all records. In text field for each record there are multiple pairs delimited  by marker :  [start_marker_description]description[end_marker_description] followed by [start_marker_code]code[end_marker_code] I want to generate multiple text files code~description to be loaded into Lucene index.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still having trouble understanding you. Please edit the question to clarify it. Fundamentally, if you *have* to retrieve millions of rows, you need to accept that that will take a fairly long time... have you *tried* just using a long CommandTimeout, and if so, what happened?